# rich:extendedDataTable selectionItems "not stored"

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm trying to use an extendedDataTable, here is some piece of the code, the xhtml part:

```
<h:form>
             <rich:extendedDataTable id="network_table" value="#{NetworkBean.availableNetworkList()}" var="network" selection="#{NetworkBean.selection}" selectionMode="single" >
                  <a4j:ajax execute="@form" event="selectionchange" listener="#{NetworkBean.selectionListener}"/>



              <rich:column>
                                 <f:facet name="header">Available Networks</f:facet>
                                 <h:outputText value="#{network}"/>
             </rich:column>    
         </rich:extendedDataTable>
         <a4j:commandButton value="1" action="#{NetworkBean.availableMssList()}">

         </a4j:commandButton >
       </h:form>
```

and some part of the backing bean:

```
 private Collection<Object> selection;
 private List<String> selectionItems = new ArrayList<String>();
 public void selectionListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        UIExtendedDataTable dataTable = (UIExtendedDataTable) event.getComponent();
        Object originalKey = dataTable.getRowKey();
        selectionItems.clear();
        for (Object selectionKey : selection) {
            dataTable.setRowKey(selectionKey);
            if (dataTable.isRowAvailable()) {
                System.out.print((String) dataTable.getRowData());
                selectionItems.add((String) dataTable.getRowData());
                System.out.print(selectionItems);
            }
        }
        dataTable.setRowKey(originalKey);
    }



public Collection<Object> getSelection() {
        return selection;
    }
/**
 * @param selection the selection to set
 */
public void setSelection(Collection<Object> selection) {
    this.selection = selection;
}

/**
 * @return the selectionItems
 */

public String getSelectionItem() {
    if (selectionItems == null || selectionItems.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return selectionItems.get(0);
}

public List<String> getSelectionItems() {
    return selectionItems;
}

/**
 * @param selectionItems the selectionItems to set
 */
public void setSelectionItems(List<String> selectionItems) {
    this.selectionItems = selectionItems;
}

public void availableMssList(){
System.out.print("hithere");
    System.out.println(selectionItems);

}
```

SO my problem is with the selectionItems, if i click on a row it works fine and prints me the selected row to the console(two printout in the Listener). But when i try to use the method availableMssList with the a4j commandbutton the selectionItems seems to be empty. What could be the problem?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does `NetworkBean.availableNetworkList()` do? Could you provide the code?

Comment: It returns a List of Strings which contains the name of networks, it works and displayed correctly

Comment: I suspect that somwhere along the way your `selectionItems` object gets changed. Try the following: place a breakpoint in `setSelectionItems` and see when it gets invoked or determine whether the collection object used in `selectionListener` is the same as in `availableMssList`.

Comment: I put some printout at  selectionItems getter and Setter but it seems none of them is called, what could be the reason?

Comment: Well maybe there is no need for calling them - depends on the rest of your code. Have you checked if the same `selectionItems` object is accessed from `availableMssList` and `selectionListener` methods?

Comment: How could i make sure it is the same?

Comment: Compare the hash codes `selectionItem.hashCode()`  or mark objects in your [IDE](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/setting-labels-to-variables-objects-and-watches.html)

Comment: Finally i found the problem.. I was so stupid, the scope of the Bean was RequestScoped thats why it wasn't stored. Anyway Thanks for the help dratewka!